Using grep count how many books have been published by an author in a certain time period
I'm currently learning grep as well as regex / other shell tools. The input txt file is of a library that contains authors, their books, and editions
ISBN Title Edition Author Year
8298 foo 3 Charles 1999


I need to use grep to find the total number of books that were published between a certain time period (example, 1993-2008).
I have tried:
grep -E ', (19(7[5-9]|[89][0-9])|200[0-5])$'

This didn't produce any result.
I also tried a regex that I came up with, which does produce the right number, but the regex isn't correct.
\s(197[5-9]|198[0-9]|199[0-9]|200[0-5])

Sorry for the vagueness in the question. Also, I'm running on WSL if that makes a difference.

grep is the wrong tool for this. awk is the way to go.

Yeah I looked around and saw that awk was the right tool to use. This is for a class I was taking and needed us to use grep. I think I've figured it out though, thanks.

Without a credible attempt of your own in the question, or at least an account of what you searched for and why the results were not helpful, this risks getting closed as too broad (the current formulation of the close reason is "needs more focus"). Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. Maybe see also what’s on-topic. and Stack Overflow homework FAQ

When you say "using grep, find authors..." - does that mean you only want the value of the Author field output, not the whole line? When asking any question about pattern matching, always include a few sample input lines that do and don't match the pattern as well as the complete expected output.

Your recent edit is problematic on multiple accounts. The attempts you added don't seem to be genuine, you added a new requirement which invalidates all the existing answers, and you turned the title into a train wreck.

You can use this
awk -F',' '1975 <= $5 && $5 <= 2005' books.txt

-F is used for setting the field separator, and $5 is the 5th field

In the general case, to grep a specific field in comma-separated input, specify how many comma-separated fields to skip before the match.
grep -E '^([^,]*,){4}[[:space:]]*(19(7[5-9]|89][0-9]|200[0-5])$' file.csv

The expression [^,]*, matches one field and the comma after it, i.e. zero or more characters which are not comma followed by one which is. By anchoring to beginning of line ^ and specifying four repetitions of this expression which skips one field, we target the beginning of the fifth.
Some, but not all, grep implementations allow you to generalize the final anchor to (,|$) i.e. to look for either another comma (for lines with more than five fields) or end of line (for lines with exactly five).
In real life, CSV files can contain quoted fields which embed a literal comma, so then you need a more complex regular expression. Real-life CSV files can also contain quoted fields which span multiple lines, so then grep (or nontrivial Awk) alone will not cut it.
(Also, real CSV files don't have spaces after the commas.)

A portable generalization of "another comma, or end of line" is "optionally, comma followed by anything, followed by end of line" i.e. (,.*)?$

Since year appears at end of line, and assuming each record is a single line:
grep -E ', (19(7[5-9]|[89][0-9])|200[0-5])$'


I think I've figured it out though.
\s(197[5-9]|198[0-9]|199[0-9]|200[0-5])

If anyone has a better solution, do let me know. Thanks.

That'll match titles like 2001: A Space Odyssey. Which was published in 1968 so is outside your range...

\s is not portable. Some grep implementations support it; but the portable equivalent is [[:space:]]

Also, you need grep -E or alternatively backslash (, |, and ) in your regex. (Or, provide multiple expressions like grep -e '[[:space:]]197[5-9]$' -e '[[:space:]]19[89][0-9]$' -e '[[:space:]]200[0-5]$')

That looks like a solution ChatGPT would come up with in as much as it looks plausible but is wrong.
